# iPhone 6 mobile Safari Cursor position in textarea fields

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have this webapp running which is pretty much a chat-widget that you can implement on your website. The DOM structure is as following

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <iframe1 ../> // chat body
   <iframe2 ../> // chat toggle
  </body>
</html>
```

which looks like this on the mobile browser:
[image]

On the very bottom we have a `textarea` element. Once you tap on it the virtual keyboard of the mobile device gets opened and it looks as following:

[image]

Once you start typing and try to select the text itself you see that the cursor position is offset. This only happens on the iPhone 6 mobile Safari as far as I am aware. All other tested mobile devices / browsers seem to work fine.

I have found a related issue which is being described here : https://github.com/18F/web-design-standards/issues/277

I realized that if you hold your finger on the textarea field and try to scroll the page down (which sometimes works), then it appears as if the cursor position is stuck on its position whilst the rest ob the webpage scrolls.

When you manage to scroll the app further down so that the textarea is right where the current wide button with the *x* is located, then the cursor position seems to align with the text that you inputed.

The bottom container, containing the textarea is built as following:

```
   <div class="container"> // position fixed to the bottom of iframe1
      <div class="container2"> // position relative
         // menu button positioned absolute
         // textarea field positioned with margin to each side
         // file icon positioned absolute
      </div>
   </div>
```